# Zywall USG 100 Disable DHCP

Tags: dhcp

I have picked up a ZyWall USG 100 and I want to disable the DHCP server on this device.

I can't do this from the Web Console and I can't find the CLI command to accomplish this either.

Is possible to disable the DHCP server on this device??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this per interface, and you *can* disable it in the Web Console. It is an interface service.

Configuration -> Network -> Interface to get to the Ethernet Summary Screen. Select an interface, click on the Edit icon. Go to the DHCP Setting section and change it.

See the [ZyWALL USG 100/200 Series User's Guide](ftp://ftp.zyxel.com/ZYWALL_USG_100/user_guide/ZYWALL%20USG%20100_2.20.pdf), starting on page 296.

[image]